# js.erb can't get params from Rails Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to get some value from Rails Controller.

**Controller**

```
  def feeling
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
    @question = @quiz.questions.find(params[:id])
    @feeling_value = params[:feeling_value]

    puts "question: #{@question.id}"
    puts "value: #{@feeling_value}"
  end
```

Output in the Rails server console:

```
question: 67
value: bad
```

**js.erb**

```
console.log("start");

var feeling_value = <%= @feeling_value %>;
console.log(feeling_value);

console.log("end");
```

Output in the Chrome console:

```
start
```

If comment *feeling_value*:

```
console.log("start");

# var feeling_value = <%= @feeling_value %>;
# console.log(feeling_value);

console.log("end");
```

Output in the Chrome console,

```
start
end
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="item ui-selectee ui-selected" id="item-good" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/quizzes/5/questions/67/feeling?feeling_value=good">Good</a>
```

I do `remote: true` in the view like before, but this time it's very strange. I can't get value from the Controller.

At first, I want to use jQuery-ui, but I didn't do it. So I remove jQuery-ui from Rails ( **Gemfile** & **application.js** ), but keep some custome stylesheets in the **application.scss**.

**Please help me out of this, Thanks.**

Comment: `var feeling_value = "<%= @feeling_value %>";`. Be careful when echoing back params in javascript through as thats how XSS attacks happen.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you max. Could you make a answer, so I can accept it. Another question, how to do if I want to pass a boolean value, like `true` of `false`? @max

Comment: I understood it, there are no question now. Thank you very much. @max

Comment: `<%= true.to_s %>` - this should be without quotes. But I would consider using a hash and calling `.to_json` on it.

Comment: I'm interest about what you said. I did some search but no result. Can you show me a example or a link? Thank you max again.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html